# webpack независимые сборки

Tags: typescript, webpack, jest

есть структура

```
node_modules/
    package.json

folder1/
    webpack.config.js
    jest.config.js
    tsconfig.json

folder2/
    webpack.config.js
    jest.config.js
    tsconfig.json
```

как вызывать независимо каждую сборку (напр /root/.../folder1/yarn build)
пока решение - в каждую сборку добавлять package.json, где будет только блок scripts{test:jest, build: webpack}
но при этом приходится указывать относительный путь, а сборки будут на разных уровнях

если scripts будет только в корне, то webpack не видит конфиг